# How to query a menu tree from mysql db

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called menudf.

This table contains the layout of a menu structure.
The child menu item knows its parent and the child knows its predecessor
this allows menus to be displayed in a fixed order of unknown depth.

```
Table name menudf
Column menudf_iden_u (its own guid)
Column menudf_iden_p (menu item knows its parent guid)
column menudf_iden_s (menu item knows its predecessor guid.
Column oms description of menu item.
```

The top GUID = 0x0000d780

Now my question how can I query the tree structure with a query? so I can query the full tree structure in the mysql database?

mysql Ver 8.0.29-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))

Comment: MySQL 8.0 supports recursive CTE syntax, you can read about it here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive-hierarchy-traversal

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.